# Swift - How creating (all) following users feed in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get newest posts from following users using .indexOn: timestamp (I'm using UTC time to do it) But I don't know how can I filter following posts as sorted with timestamp simultaneously to be able to use **limitToLast** correctly in this case?

```
posts
   post_id_0
      timestamp: _
      ownerID: user_id_0
   ...


users
   user_id_0
      following
         user_id_0: true
         user_id_1: true
      followers
         user_id_x: true
         user_id_y: true
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order by timestamp and limit it to the last one (which would be the most recent)

```
    let postsRef = self.myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("posts")

    postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("timestamp").queryLimitedToLast(1)
       .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
            print("not found")

        } else {
            for child in snapshot.children {

                let q = child.value["ownerID"] as! String
                print(q)
            }

        }
    })
```

If I understand the question, you also want to limit the posts to a specific user. In other words you want to get the most current post(s) created by user_0.  (i.e. and query:  where xx && yy)

There are a few ways of doing it

1) Track which posts those are within the user node

```
users
  user_id_0
     following
       xxxx
     followers
       yyyy
     3_most_recent_posts
       post_id_3: true
       post_id_2: true
       post_id_1: true
```

Then you can simply fetch the specific posts directly.

2) A second option would be formatting your Firebase to match what you want to get:

```
posts
   post_id_0
       owner_timestamp: user_id_0_20160611081433
```

Then, query the posts node for values starting at user_id_0_ and limiting it to the last x

```
    postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("owner_timestamp")
       .queryStartingAtValue("user_id_0_")
       .queryLimitedToLast(1)
       .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
            print("not found")

        } else {
            for child in snapshot.children {

                let q = child.value["ownerID"] as! String
                print(q)
            }

        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your description, actually I wonder that how can I get all following user's posts to sort with timestamp & limit all together like my facebook timeline from friends? Could you add your opinion for this case?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it. Your follow up comment is really a separate question that will require a different answer. I would suggest posting it and lets see what the community suggests.

Comment: I have already thought one following user's feeds. So I have asked here how getting all following users feeds sorting by timestamp and limit together.